# How do i remove "new line" from a command that ends in | wc -l in perl

Tags: perl

ps efax 2>/dev/null|grep firstbo|grep -v grep|wc -l

if i store this as a scalar, then, the scalar contains a new line, how do i remove the new line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
chomp $scalar;
```

But everything after the `ps` can be done more efficiently inside your script, like this:

```
my $count = 0;
open(my $ps, "ps -e -o comm |") or die "failed to spawn ps: $!";
while(<$ps>) {
    $count++ if /firstbo/;
}
close $ps;
```

Comment: `open my $ps, ...` -- avoid globals as much as possible.

Comment: True 'dat, I've edited my code.  I learned Perl back in the days when you *had* to use barewords for filehandles, and haven't used it seriously in years.

Comment: The only problem is that this command runs on a remote host, using Net::SSH::Expect

Comment: Ah, so you want to minimize data transferred over the network?  In that case, try `ps -e -o comm | awk 'BEGIN{count=0}/[f]irstbo/{count++}END{print count}'` and you'll still need to `chomp` your scalar.

Comment: Or `ps -e -o comm | grep -c '[f]irstbo'` will be even more efficient, if you have GNU coreutils on the remote host.

Comment: so complicated... `scalar(@{[qx(ps -efa)]});`

Comment: I don't get what the `@{[ ... ]}` part does, but `ps -efa` is not at all the same as `ps -e -o comm | grep [f]irstbo`, dude.

Answer (score 3):

`chomp $scalar` will eat the newline

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) operator. You can also condense your command by taking advantage of the fact that the re in `grep` stands for regular expression:

```
chomp(my $num_firstbo = `ps efax 2>/dev/null | grep [f]irstbo | wc -l`);
```

By matching against a singleton character class, the command above matches processes whose argvs contain `firstbo`, but not the `grep` command itself.